# Read multiple partitions into one dataframe/rdd

Tags: sql, apache-spark

```
val rdd = spark.read.format("csv")
                    .option("delimiter","\t").option("header", "false") 
                    .csv("/mnt/adls/myDb/myTb/s_year_month=201806/s_day=10")
```

Now this reads in data for a specific partition (20180610).  Is there a way I can read all partitions in the `myTb` folder into one rdd? So it can later by accessed like this

```
SELECT * FROM  myDb.myTb WHERE (CONCAT(s_year_month, s_day) = '20180610')
```

If I did just wild card read, it would lose the partitioning aspect.

Comment: @user8371915 Yes, I know how to load all files, however they lose its partitioning and it just becomes one big cluster with no partitioning .

Comment: Note `basePath` option.